# Tensorflow/Keras LSTM RNN model for consumption forecast not learning/underfitting

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

Hi everyone I need help!

I have build a LSTM RNN model with Tensorflow and Keras to predict the electricity consumption of a building. I have half hourly data since august 2021 (just above 4 million rows). I have tried to play with the number of LSTM layer, L1/l2, sequence length (using 48 to capture a full day), changed the learning rate, also added some features like hour_of_day, is_weekend etc..

But my model doesn't seem to learn, the training loss is quite high (around 16) and my actual data only vary from 0 to 65 (see graph consumption across time for the data splitting and overall pattern of the data[consumption across time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaQKX.png)).
The predicted values are much smaller than the actual values:[Predicted versus actual values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDEvb.png)

As you can see below the validation loss is always smaller than the training loss and they do not converge.
[Training vs validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRnwb.png)

1)- Have I scaled my features properly with StandardScaler? why are my predicted values varying from 0 to 3 while the actual values vary from 0 to 65?
2)- Are my sequences created properly?
3)- Can you spot an error in my code that would lead to underfitting?
4)- If no error in my code what can you suggest to stop my model underfitting?

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1, l2
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU

# Load preprocessed Df
df_LSTM = df.copy() 

# Specify the target variable
target_column = 'consumption'

# Standardize (normalize) the numerical features using StandardScaler for all the dataset (train, validation, and testing)
scaler = StandardScaler()
features_to_scale = ['year', 'month', 'day_of_week', 'hour', 'hour_of_day', 'is_daytime', 'is_weekend']

scaler.fit(df_LSTM[features_to_scale])

df_LSTM_scaled = df_LSTM.copy()  # Create a copy to avoid modifying the original df
df_LSTM_scaled[features_to_scale] = scaler.transform(df_LSTM_scaled[features_to_scale])

# Encode the occupier categorical feature using LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df_LSTM_scaled['occupier'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df_LSTM_scaled['occupier'])

# Prepare sequences for the LSTM model
def create_sequences(data, sequence_length):
    sequences = []
    targets = []
    for i in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        seq_data = data[i:i+sequence_length, :-1]  # All features - the last column of df which is the target column 'consumption'
        target = data[i+sequence_length, -1]  # Target variable (last column =consumption)
        sequences.append(seq_data)
        targets.append(target)
    return np.array(sequences), np.array(targets)

sequence_length = 5  # to adjust

X, y = create_sequences(df_LSTM_scaled.to_numpy(), sequence_length)

# Split the data into training, validation and test dataset
train_start_date = '2021-08-01'
train_end_date = '2023-01-31'
val_start_date = '2023-02-01'
val_end_date = '2023-06-01'
test_start_date = '2023-06-02'
test_end_date = '2023-10-18'

train_df = df_LSTM_scaled[(df_LSTM_scaled.index >= train_start_date) & (df_LSTM_scaled.index <= train_end_date)]
val_df = df_LSTM_scaled[(df_LSTM_scaled.index >= val_start_date) & (df_LSTM_scaled.index <= val_end_date)]
test_df = df_LSTM_scaled[(df_LSTM_scaled.index >= test_start_date) & (df_LSTM_scaled.index <= test_end_date)]


X_train = X[:len(train_df) - sequence_length]
y_train = y[:len(train_df) - sequence_length]
X_val = X[len(train_df) - sequence_length:len(train_df) - sequence_length + len(val_df)]
y_val = y[len(train_df) - sequence_length:len(train_df) - sequence_length + len(val_df)]
X_test = X[len(train_df) - sequence_length + len(val_df):len(train_df) - sequence_length + len(val_df) + len(test_df)]
y_test = y[len(train_df) - sequence_length + len(val_df):len(train_df) - sequence_length + len(val_df) + len(test_df)]


X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_val = X_val.astype('float32')
y_train = y_train.astype('float32')
y_val = y_val.astype('float32')

# Create and configure the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='tanh', input_shape=(sequence_length, X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))  
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='mse')

# Define early stopping criteria
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
    epochs=25,  
    batch_size=64,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],  # Add the early stopping callback
    verbose=2
)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
mse = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f'Test Mean Squared Error (MSE): {mse}')

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Plot actual vs. predicted values
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(y_test, label='Actual')
plt.plot(y_pred, label='Predicted')
plt.xlabel('Time Steps')
plt.ylabel('Electricity Consumption')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```